# Spanish Text not rendering properly

Tags: wordpress, localization

My Wordpress site with Spanish Text not rendering properly: Just like this  �

http://projects.dev2d.com/msleximus/

I have tried with UTF 8, if its the issues of ISO-8859-1 then how to remove?

FYI: current index page data not coming from DB.

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced those words with HTML code for e.g á and its done now.